# Ways to create an intent:

Tags: android, android-studio

I know 2 ways to create an `Intent`, they are:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(com.example.android.somepackagename, com.example.android.somepackagename.Activity2);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am aware that both do essentially the same thing, wondering if there were any behind the scenes differences, and if there were special cases where we NEED to use only one type.

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am aware that both do essentially the same thing

No, they do *exactly* the same thing... if `com.example.android.somepackagename` is your own package.

The implementation of the two-parameter constructor is:

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageContext, cls);
}
```

The implementation of `setClassName()` is:

```
public Intent setClassName(String packageName, String className) {
    mComponent = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
    return this;
}
```

They both set the `ComponentName`. If you go into the `ComponentName` source, the one that takes the `Context` just calls `getPackageName()` on the `Context` and uses that `String`.

`setClassName()` can be used to create an `Intent` that identifies a component in a separate package, which your `Intent` constructor cannot. This is relatively uncommon, as we usually use implicit `Intents` (e.g., `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)`) for finding and invoking components from other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are essentially same. Just in the second case you explicitly mention the full path of activity including package name. However, both will guarantee to execute. Also note that in these cases your activity doesn't need an intent-filter specified.

However, there's another way

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.someactivity");

In this case you specify an ACTION name. Here, your someactivity must have an intent filter with the same action. Important to note that if there is another application with an activity which has an intent filter with the same action name, then when launching the activity, the user will get an activity picker dialog to choose which one to use.